# Internal Error Java program Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums

I have the error while executing the java program in Intellij IDE. Any thoughts what might be the issue.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) No enum constant org.jetbrains.jps.model.java.LanguageLevel.JDK_1_9
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.jetbrains.jps.model.java.LanguageLevel.JDK_1_9
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.java.LanguageLevel.valueOf(LanguageLevel.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.java.JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension$JavaProjectExtensionSerializer.loadExtension(JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension.java:285)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.java.JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension$JavaProjectExtensionSerializer.loadExtension(JpsJavaModelSerializerExtension.java:268)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadComponents(JpsLoaderBase.java:59)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.a(JpsProjectLoader.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have configured `JDK1_8`. But still it is showing as `1_9`.

Comment: JDK_1_9 ? Did you configure Java 9 somewhere?

Comment: Same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499590/android-studio-import-maven-project-cause-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-n

Comment: Android Studio does not have official support for JDK_1.8 yet. There are some libraries around to use lambdas.

Comment: That sounds like a viable answer @Proverbio, either on this question or the one Thilo linked.

Comment: I am not using any stuffs that are related to Android. I just want to run my Java project... The project just performs some file read/ file write and comparison. Nothing much..

Comment: It would be good, if it is possible to de-link Android Studio..

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on the root of your project explorer and choose `Open Module Settings` (it's near the bottom of the menu on my machine). Choose `Project` on the resulting window and look at your sdk and language level. Choose 1.8 for the project sdk, and 8.0 for the language level.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Even if I still don't get why the language level changed during my vacation. I avoided the IntelliJ upgrade from 2018.2 to 2019.1 precisely because I got in trouble last time...

Comment: I had the same problem, but between java 11 and 17. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Did what others here recommended to do.
What finally resolved it was removing the following **plugin** entry from my pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <!-- or whatever version you use -->
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugins>
</build>
```

So I suggest you check all your pom.xml files

Answer (score 0):

[2019] ->

Check your run configurations:

1. Hit CRTL+SHIFT+A
2. Write "Edit configurations" And choose the option "Edit Configurations..."
3. Select your Application node and select the "Configuration" tab.
4. Check the JRE dropdown. See if that option is still 1.9 or so. Or change it there for a more suitable version.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading IntelliJ fixed this issue for me. Apparently the JDK version I used  (15) was not support in my older IntelliJ install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that was fixed by switching to the latest version of Java
In this Case you Should Change To JDK 9 or another latest Version.

Answer (score -2):

Android Studio does not have official support for JDK_1.8 yet. There are some [libraries](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) around to use lambdas.

Comment: OP mentioned in comments that he's not trying to do any form of android development, so -1.